# I want to summarize information across multiple pages by item using Scrapy (understanding cb_kwargs)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

**Goal**: I want to retrieve order performance data published on a specific e-commerce site. Since those data are spread across multiple pages for each order performance, we would like to extract the information for each page and finally summarize them as a single item or record.

I have looked through the official documentation and other similar Q.A.'s and found some.
From the information, I was able to get an idea that it might be possible to achieve this by using cb_kwargs.
However, I could not understand what is wrong with the following code.

- [python - Interpreting callbacks and cb_kwargs with scrapy - Stack
  Overflow]
  ([Interpreting callbacks and cb_kwargs with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462844/interpreting-callbacks-and-cb-kwargs-with-scrapy))
- [python - Multiple pages per item in Scrapy.
  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201876/multiple-pages-per-item-in-scrapy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The program runs, but the csv outputs nothing as shown in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQMZs.png)

The order results page contains information on 30 items per page.
I would like to first retrieve all of the signup dates for each, which are listed only on the first page, then move to each product page from there to retrieve the details, and then store those information one item at a time.

I am a beginner who started writing code in Python 3 months ago.
So I may have some problems with basic understanding about classes, etc.
I would appreciate it if you could point this out to me during our discussion.
The official documentation of scrapy is too unfriendly for beginners and I am having a hard time with it.

```
 def parse_firstpage_item(self, response): 
            request = scrapy.Request(
                url=response.url,
                callback=self.parse_productpage_item,
                cb_kwargs=dict(product_URL='//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a'))
    
            loader = ItemLoader(item = BuymaResearchtoolItem(), response = response)
    
            loader.add_xpath("Conversion_date", '//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[3]/text()')
    
            yield loader.load_item()
    
    
        def parse_productpage_item(self, response, product_URL): 
    
            loader = ItemLoader(item = BuymaResearchtoolItem(), response = response)
    
            loader.add_xpath("brand_name", 'normalize-space(//*[@id="s_brand"]/dd/a/text())')
           
            loader.add_value("page_URL" , response.url) 
            loader.add_xpath("inquire" , '//*[@id="tabmenu_inqcnt"]/text()')
    
            yield loader.load_item()
```

```
class MyLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def extract_links(self, response):
        base_url = get_base_url(response)
        if self.restrict_xpaths:

            docs = [
                subdoc
                for x in self.restrict_xpaths
                for subdoc in response.xpath(x)
            ]
        else:
            docs = [response.selector]
        all_links = []
        for doc in docs:
            links = self._extract_links(doc, response.url, response.encoding, base_url)
            all_links.extend(self._process_links(links))
        logging.info('='*100)
        logging.info(all_links)
        logging.info(f'total liks len: {len(all_links)}')
        logging.info('='*100)
        return all_links


class AllSaledataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'all_salesdata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.buyma.com']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.buyma.com/buyer/9887867/sales_1.html']
   
    rules = (
        Rule(MyLinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="buyeritem_name"]/a'), callback='parse_firstpage_item', follow=False),
           
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//DIV[@class="pager"]/DIV/A[contains(text(),"次")]'),follow=False)
            )
    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
            return
        seen = set()
        for rule_index, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)]
                    #if lnk not in seen]
            for link in rule.process_links(links):
                seen.add(link)
                request = self._build_request(rule_index, link)
                yield rule.process_request(request, response)

    def start_requests(self):
     with open('/Users/morni/buyma_researchtool/buyma_researchtool/AllshoppersURL.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = str(row[2])[:-5]+'/sales_1.html')
        for row in self.reader:
            for n in range(1, 300):
                url = f'{self.base_page}{row}/sales_{n}.html'
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    url=url,
                    callback=self.parse_firstpage_item,
                    errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                    dont_filter=True
                    )        

    def parse_firstpage_item(self, response): 

        loader = ItemLoader(item = BuymaResearchtoolItem(), response = response)

        loader.add_xpath("Conversion_date", '//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[3]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath("product_name" , '//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a/text()')
        loader.add_value("product_URL" , '//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a/@href')
        item = loader.load_item()

        yield scrapy.Request(
        url=response.urljoin(item['product_URL']),
        callback=self.parse_productpage_item,
        cb_kwargs={'item': item},
        )

    def parse_productpage_item(self, response, item):

        loader = ItemLoader(item=item, response = response)

        loader.add_xpath("brand_name", 'normalize-space(//*[@id="s_brand"]/dd/a/text())')
        〜

        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: please share more of your code...

Comment: I've added all the code for Spider!

Comment: Does that mean @gangabass answer wasn't helpful?

Comment: I rewrote it based on @gangabass's response.
But it still does not work well. When I run the program, the first parse method seems to work, but the second method does not seem to work.
Perhaps the url specification (url=item['product_URL']) in the yield scrapy request returned in the first method is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call each page and pass your current item to callback:

```
def parse_first_page(self, response): 
    loader = ItemLoader(item = BuymaResearchtoolItem(), response = response)
    loader.add_xpath("brand_name", 'normalize-space(//*[@id="s_brand"]/dd/a/text())')
    loader.add_value("page_URL" , response.url) 
    loader.add_xpath("inquire" , '//*[@id="tabmenu_inqcnt"]/text()')
    item = loader.load_item()

    yield scrapy. Request(
        url=second_page_url,
        callback=self.parse_second_page,
        cb_kwargs={'item': item},
    )

def parse_second_page(self, response, item): 
    loader = ItemLoader(item=item, response=response)
    loader.add_xpath("Conversion_date", '//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[3]/text()')
    item = loader.load_item()

    yield scrapy. Request(
        url=third_page_url,
        callback=self.parse_third_page,
        cb_kwargs={'item': item},
    )

def parse_third_page(self, response, item): 
    loader = ItemLoader(item=item, response=response)
    loader.add_value('ThirdUrl', response.url)
    yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
I rewrote it based on your response.
But it still does not work well. When I run the program, the first parse method seems to work, but the second method does not seem to work.
Perhaps the url specification (url=item['product_URL']) in the yield scrapy request returned in the first method is wrong.

Comment: What error do you have? Did you try `response.urljoin(item['product_URL'])` ?

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments".

Comment: Are you sure that your `product_URL` selector works?

Comment: Yes. For XPath, I can definitely get 30 product links.

Comment: I'm sure that your XPath is wrong because this `//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a` return not a **href**. You definitely need `//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a/@href` instead

Comment: I changed it to try and got the same following error.

  File "/Users/morni/buyma_researchtool/buyma_researchtool/spiders/all_salesdata.py", line 121, in parse_firstpage_item
    url=response.urljoin(item['product_URL']),
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I've added almost all of the source code for crawler, but do you need anything else?
If necessary, I will add it.

Comment: I need your **actual** code. Because, as I said, you're trying to use `//*[@id="buyeritemtable"]/div/ul/li[2]/p[1]/a` as an URL but this XPath returns HTML anchor element (not a string!)

Comment: We completely rewrote the code on the question to the actual code we are currently running.
I am getting the same error when I run it with this code.